# NormalCDF returning error

Tags: probability

I'm trying to find the probability that $X$ is greater than, given a mean of $50$ and a std deviation of $5$.

I enter `normalcdf(66, 1E99, 50, 5)` in my calculator and receive and error.

Please help.

Comment: Could you explicitly write the event you are trying to compute the probability of? For instance, let $X \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu, \sigma\right)$, are you trying to evaluate $\Pr\left(a < X< b\right)$ for some $a$ and $b$, or are you doing something else? You can also use Wolfram|Alpha, for instance to evaluate $\Pr(X>66)$ ([link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Pr%28X%3E66%2C+x+distributed+normal%2850%2C5%29%29))

Comment: You're trying to find the probability that $X$ is greater than what value?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to reset your calculator and try the equation again.

Are you sure your syntax was all good?

If the information you provided is good then the result to this question should be 6.872 * e^(-4) [that's what I found using my calculator - it is the TI-84 Plus Silver Edition)

Comment: I think that you are confused between Probability Distribution Function PDF and Culmulative Distribution Function CDF...because look again at your syntax, it was CDF yes? the property of 0 ≤ f(x) ≤ 1 only works for PDF...In CDF the results vary between your lower and upper bound. I hope this explaination can help you to understand it. Correct me if I'm wrong cuz we are working on this topic right now in our math lessons.